# Using union clause throws exception when using a ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to show a ExpandableListView using a ExpandableListAdapter. I am having several problems. The first was using UNION as follows:

```
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select ig._id, ig.nombre, 0 tipo from InteresGrupo ig where ig.nombre<>'General' "+
                             "union "+
                             "select i._id, i.nombre, 1 tipo from Interes i "+
                             "inner join InteresGrupo g on i.interesGrupo=g._id "+
                             "where g.nombre='General' "+
                             "order by ig.nombre", null);
```

That thrown the next exception:

```
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

The SQL was working perfectly trying in a SQLite editor. Finally I could make it work changing "UNION" for "UNION ALL" (I still do not know why).

Next problem (still unsolved) came when I tried to order the elements. I used the next sentence:

```
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select ig._id, ig.nombre, 0 tipo from InteresGrupo ig where ig.nombre<>'General' "+
                             "union all "+
                             "select i._id, i.nombre, 1 tipo from Interes i "+
                             "inner join InteresGrupo g on i.interesGrupo=g._id "+
                             "where g.nombre='General' "+
                             "order by 2", null);
```

Again the same exception. SQL sentence works again well in the SQLite editor, so I am thinking there must be some limitations in the use of SQL sentences with the adapter.

The exception is thrown before any of the methods of the adapter is called so it has nothing to do with the code inside the adapter, but just the SQL sentence (I guess). I happens in the third of the next three lines:

```
    ExpandableListView epView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.lvIntereses);
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(cur, this);
    epView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Anyone could give a tip?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
"union all"+"select ....
```

Results in `union allselect`..

You need a space between union all and select

Ex. `"union all " + "select ....`

or just `"union all select ..."`

Comment: Also, you have "order by 2" .. not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Sorry dymmeh. Editing the code to post my answer I put "union all"+"select..." but the sentence was right in my real code (I edited my question to correct this mistake). The problem wasn't the sentence because you get a sql sintax error when that happens.

Comment: I am trying the ExpandableListView to show the elements in that order (by "nombre"). Without the "order by" clause everything works well but the list shown is not ordered.

Comment: @Martillador81 Why do you have "order by 2" ? is that also a typo? Shouldn't it be "order by ig.nombre"?

Comment: "order by 2" is supposed to be the same as "order by ig.nombre" (it means order by column 2). It works when I do the query in Firefox SQLite Manager. I have used this notation widely in other DBMS.